# Detect and get name of an app launched

Tags: java, android, service

I've read all the solutions about this topic on stack and I've tried all the solutions, but still I have not found anything about my problem.

Is there any way to detect from a service when an app, I don't know package, is launched?

I need something like:

- my app run in Background
- user launches an app
- my service detects the name of the app
- my service show a toast with the name

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hii You can try this in your service
which will check every one second for the current app, prior lollipop you will use this code,

```
final ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
```

Comment: Is there ant way to get a trigger when the app is launched, so to save battery